# Grid Color Change

Tags: java, chess

can somebody please help me create a chess like board. I need to change the color the grid to black and white. I tried to use a an if statement `if (r % 2 = 0) then rectfilcolor`, but it colors the hall row.

```
package grid;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class grid extends JPanel {
    public static int High=640;
    public static int width=617;
    public static int row=3,column=3;
    public static JFrame Frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        grid gride= new grid();
        Frame= new JFrame();
        Frame.setSize(width, High);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(Frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        Frame.add(gride);
        gride.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (int r=0; r<4; r++) {
            g.drawLine(r*(600/3), 0, r*(600/3), 600);

            for (int c=0; c<4; c++) {
                 g.drawLine(0,(c*(600/3)), 600, (c*(600/3)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-------------------------------------Edited----------------------------------

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

      for (int r=0;r<4;r++){
          g.drawLine(r*(600/3), 0, r*(600/3), 600);
          if (r%2!=0){
              g.setColor(Color.white);
              g.fillRect(r*(600/3), 0, r*(600/3), 600);
          }


      for (int c=0;c<4;c++){
          g.drawLine(0,(c*(600/3)), 600, (c*(600/3)));
          if(c%2!=0){
              g.setColor(Color.black);

              g.fillRect(0,(c*(600/3)), 600, (c*(600/3)));
          }

      }
      }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember to call super.paintComponent(g) to initialize the JPanel canvas correctly.

You can use `g.fillRect(x, y, width, height)` method to draw each chess cell. Use `g.setColor(color)` to change the color of the painting.

Therefore:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};
    int lengthUnit = (600 / 3);
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++ row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; ++col) {
            g.setColor(colors[(row + col) % 2]); // alternate between black and white
            g.fillRect(row * lengthUnit, col * lengthUnit, lengthUnit, lengthUnit);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: you are almost there, just need to remove some redundant statements in the nested for loop...

```
for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            if ((c + r) % 2 != 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
            }
            g.fillRect(r * (600 / 3), (c * (600 / 3)), 200, 200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user3500147 1) you never change the color of the painting 2) you are only using drawLines, which doesn't draw an area

Comment: i had this after my second for loop. if(r%2==0){ g.fillrect(r*60,0,r*60,400)}

Comment: @user3500147 can you update your question so that I know what exactly is going on?

Comment: i added the edited one and as you can see it on create a plus sign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94513/discussion-between-bond-and-user3500147).